# Postgresql 9.2 - Auto vacuum running continuously for 18+ hours

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, vacuum

I currently have a table that is updated daily (easily 20%+ rows are updated, all floats/integers) and the vacuum is kicking off and running for more than 18 hours.  There are 19 million rows total.

Does this seem indicative of a problem?  It slows the entire database down and it's running on a pretty powerful machine (32 cores, 128 GB RAM, SSD).

Any suggestions on how to correct/fix/debug further?

All vacuum settings are default.

Comment: You may want to consider doing a manual `VACUUM` after the `UPDATE`. It'll put more load on the DB, but it should run faster as it doesn't respect `autovaccum_cost_delay`. So if you do your bulk update during a quiet period, you might want to vacuum the resulting dead rows then too.

Comment: It might also help to make sure your `FILLFACTOR` on the table is set to about `80` or `75`. That will encourage space to be left for future updates, hopefully allowing cheaper HOT updates to occur more.